# Gradient not covering the image ios swift 3 on iphone plus devices

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

[image]

I have created a view which holds my gradient but the gradient is not applying over the whole image/view. This issue is usually observed in iPhone plus devices.

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewBanner: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewGradient: UIView!

    let color1 = UIColor(red: 48.0/255.0, green: 178.0/255.0, blue: 166.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let color2 = UIColor(red: 82.0/255.0, green: 96.0/255.0, blue: 169.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.viewGradient.frame = self.viewGradient.bounds
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.viewGradient.frame.size.height)
        self.viewGradient.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: i think there is an issue to setting frame male sure  gradientLayer.frame are same of your viewgradient frame please do printf

Comment: Try to run code in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.viewGradient.frame.size.height)
```

do above thing in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 2):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.yourView.layer.sublayers?[0].frame = self.yourView.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: add a description, explain your answer. it always helps the viewer to understand your solution.

Comment: it is obvious that he needs to resize the gradient layer evey time it renders because auto layout will not work on view layers

Comment: do not comment add it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is the full code code snippet

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     self.viewGradient.frame = self.viewGradient.bounds
     let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
     gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
     gradientLayer.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
     gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
     gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
     gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.viewGradient.frame.size.width, height: self.viewGradient.frame.size.height)
     self.viewGradient.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```